# Can I use my Visual Studio 2013 to build sharepoint add ins (Hosted App) -SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Can I use my Visual Studio 2013 to build sharepoint add ins (Hosted App) or do I need to have VS 2015 and install Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015.
Following the instructions [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/set-up-sharepoint-server-2016-project-templates-for-visual-studio-2015/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For VS 2015,  I suggest download office developer tools preview 1 by clicking

[This](https://aka.ms/officedevtoolsforvs2015)

Once you have installed it, SharePoint Addins option wil start reflecting as follows and to create share point hosted Add-in select SharePoint Addins option from the following:

[image]

Comment: Hi guys sorry I mean visual studio 2013

Answer (score 1):

You have to install [Office Developer Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/office-tools/) for building SharePoint Add-ins (**Provider-hosted** or **SharePoint-hosted**) or Office Add-ins.